# What is the best way to develop a java file transfer application?

Tags: java, file, file-transfer

in one side i have an API that store many xml files.
on the other side, an another API have to receive all these files.
i have created a service in the first API that create an ByteArrayOutputStream with all the files and return it.

But i'm not sure it's the best solution if files are too large.
How can i receive in a safe way all the xml files in my second API ?

Comment: Best is opinion based, but you seem to have asked pretty much the same question before. What was wrong with SFTP that was mentioned in your last question?

Comment: Implement the remote api, decrypt, write a rest wrapper around it. Done.

Comment: in fact the two api (the input and output) already exists and in the middle there is nothing. So i will have to mount a server and the file transfert app.  before I thought the server existed but actually no

Answer (score 2):

The best way to **develop** a file transfer system is to not develop the code yourself.  Use an existing solution.

The best way to **develop** a file transfer system in Java is to minimize the code you write yourself.  Use an existing Java library.

There are many software packages, libraries and/or protocols that you could use.  Asking us to recommend specific ones is off-topic.  When you do your research, make sure that you include your security and integrity requirements in your assessment criteria.

Comment: i I know that the less you develop yourself the better is :) but my question is on the protocol to use. i dont' think it's off-topic but a real question. each solution can have 
advantages and disadvantages

Comment: Off topic means it is not appropriate to ask here.  The fact that it is "real" is not relevant.  Please read this: ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Requests for recommendations are explicitly listed as off-topic.

Comment: By the way, if you couch this as "please list all of the alternatives and their pros and cons so that I can choose" then your question is Too Broad.  That is how others have chosen to interpret your question.   Sorry, but you are going to have to do your own research.

Comment: thank you, i understand. i have made a lot of research but it can be hard to know the best solution when you read everything and its opposite.